# Count tweets with hashtag

Tags: twitter

Is there any way to keep a count of tweets containing a specific hashtag or word? For example, keeping a count of all tweets containing the hashtag, #apple, or all tweets containing 'iphone'?

Answer (score 3):

**this php source code for get count hashtag(#) twitter**

```php
<?php
   global $total, $hashtag;
   //$hashtag = '#supportvisitbogor2011';
   $hashtag = '#australialovesjustin';
   $total = 0;
   function getTweets($hash_tag, $page) {
      global $total, $hashtag;
      $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.urlencode($hash_tag).'&';
      $url .= 'page='.$page;    
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      $json = curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);
      //echo "<pre>";    
      //$json_decode = json_decode($json);
      //print_r($json_decode->results);

      $json_decode = json_decode($json);        
      $total += count($json_decode->results);    
      if($json_decode->next_page){
         $temp = explode("&",$json_decode->next_page);        
         $p = explode("=",$temp[0]);                
         getTweets($hashtag,$p[1]);
      }        
   }

   getTweets($hashtag,1);
   echo $total;
?>
```

Thanks..

Comment: This looks nice, but will not give you a complete count, as Twitter API gives you max 100 tweets per request and doesn't let you go further down until page 15 or 16. So the most this will give you is about 1500 and no more, even if there are more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service like [DataSift](http://datasift.com) to keep track of Tweets containing certain hashtags or keywords in real time. They will also be releasing a [Historics service](http://blog.datasift.com/2011/12/07/historic/) this summer, allowing you to search back as far as January 2010